# Is there a way to inline tuple deconstruction to avoid an unnecessary allocation?

Tags: c#, struct, tuples, inline, c#-7.0

I have the following example `struct`:

```
struct Data {
    internal long a;
    internal long b;

    internal void Deconstruct(out long aa, out long bb) {
        aa = a; bb = b;
    }
}
```

What if I want only to use the values of the struct an forget about the struct itself?

```
Data Generate()
    => new Data() { a = 3, b = 5 };

void Test() {
    (var a, var b) = Generate();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

The call to `Generate` creates a struct and it is decomposed immediately in its parts. Can I somehow *inline* this process and get rid of the struct altogether?

I compiled (this class library) with VS 15.5.7 in release mode an ilspy is showing:

```
.method private hidebysig 
    instance void Test () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x208c
    // Code size 33 (0x21)
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] int64,
        [1] valuetype StackOverflowDemo.Q1/Data,
        [2] int64,
        [3] int64
    )

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: call instance valuetype StackOverflowDemo.Q1/Data StackOverflowDemo.Q1::Generate()
    IL_0006: stloc.1
    IL_0007: ldloca.s 1
    IL_0009: ldloca.s 2
    IL_000b: ldloca.s 3
    IL_000d: call instance void StackOverflowDemo.Q1/Data::Deconstruct(int64&, int64&)
    IL_0012: ldloc.2
    IL_0013: ldloc.3
    IL_0014: stloc.0
    IL_0015: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int64)
    IL_001a: ldloc.0
    IL_001b: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int64)
    IL_0020: ret
} // end of method Q1::Test
```

Comment: Well, why don't you use a `ValueTuple` in the first place? Why care to define the `struct`?

Comment: Why do you want to inline it? The JIT compiler handles inlining decisions because it has the most relevant information to whether inlining is an effective optimization. You should really be looking at JIT'd machine code.

Comment: @mikez That is a point. I thought: inline it and optimize the allocation away - which is a might not be possible.

Comment: Also which allocation would be removed? Structs don't add memory pressure to the GC so the overhead of a struct here is low compared to a class.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried that and there is indeed a difference. With the `ValueTuple`, the values are taken direct from the evaluation stack and no local variable for the `ValueTuple` is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to forget the struct, instead of

```
Data Generate()
    => new Data() { a = 3, b = 5 };
```

Why not use

```
void Generate(out long aa, out long bb)
{
    aa = 3; bb = 5;
}
```

That eliminates the struct as you asked.

If you want to keep the struct but get rid of the extra allocation, you could also do this:

```
class Data {
    public long A { get; internal set; }
    public long B { get; internal set; }

    internal Data(long a, long b) {
        A = a; B = b;
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
void Test() {
    var data = Generate();
    Console.WriteLine(data.A);
    Console.WriteLine(data.B);
}
```

Comment: While this solution works, I'd like to keep my struct. I want to define properties or other elements in it. And what if my struct consists of several more fields?

Comment: What did you think of the second half of my answer?  You  can still return a single data structure, but you don’t need to deconstruct the arguments. You can just access them as properties.And you can add as many methods as you want, including interfaces.

Comment: @ventiseis I'm really unsure of your question. Why are you deliberately using a struct, if you don't want it constructed? Why is the `void Generate(..)` suggestion not helpful here?

Comment: @Rob I'm afraid that I oversimplified the example. The `Generate` method does actually have input parameters and the struct has computed read-only properties - I'm happy to use it and pass it around as parameter or return value. But there is this case where I don't need the struct at all, only the two values from the computation. So if I don't want to duplicate the computation code, I'll have to use the struct as proposed in this answer. And I won't use tuple decomposition because it add another layer of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by *mikez*, I used `windbg` and the `sos` extension to look a the jitted code.

I learned three things from this:

- after jitting, no struct is allocated on the stack in this case
- looking at the generated il code is not enough to reason about the code executed during runtime
- this simplified example might be different to my original use case - so i'll have to look at the jitted code of my original example

Thank you for all your helpful input.

Without further modification to the original source code, this this the output of `!Name2EE` for the `Test` method:

```
C:\Users\...\source\repos\StackOverflowDemo\Q1.cs @ 37:
>>> 00007ffa`02c41d00 56              push    rsi
00007ffa`02c41d01 4883ec30        sub     rsp,30h
00007ffa`02c41d05 33c0            xor     eax,eax
00007ffa`02c41d07 4889442420      mov     qword ptr [rsp+20h],rax
00007ffa`02c41d0c 4889442428      mov     qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax
00007ffa`02c41d11 488d542420      lea     rdx,[rsp+20h]
00007ffa`02c41d16 e8dde6ffff      call    00007ffa`02c403f8 (StackOverflowDemo.Q1.Generate(), mdToken: 0000000006000003)
00007ffa`02c41d1b 488b4c2420      mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+20h]
00007ffa`02c41d20 488b742428      mov     rsi,qword ptr [rsp+28h]

C:\Users\...\source\repos\StackOverflowDemo\Q1.cs @ 38:
00007ffa`02c41d25 e8eee5ffff      call    00007ffa`02c40318 (System.Console.WriteLine(Int64), mdToken: 0000000006000080)

C:\Users\...\source\repos\StackOverflowDemo\Q1.cs @ 39:
00007ffa`02c41d2a 488bce          mov     rcx,rsi
00007ffa`02c41d2d e8e6e5ffff      call    00007ffa`02c40318 (System.Console.WriteLine(Int64), mdToken: 0000000006000080)

C:\Users\...\source\repos\StackOverflowDemo\Q1.cs @ 40:
00007ffa`02c41d32 90              nop
00007ffa`02c41d33 4883c430        add     rsp,30h
00007ffa`02c41d37 5e              pop     rsi
00007ffa`02c41d38 c3              ret
```

And for the `Generate` method:

```
C:\Users\...\source\repos\StackOverflowDemo\Q1.cs @ 28:
>>> 00007ffa`02c41d50 b803000000      mov     eax,3
00007ffa`02c41d55 b905000000      mov     ecx,5
00007ffa`02c41d5a 488902          mov     qword ptr [rdx],rax
00007ffa`02c41d5d 48894a08        mov     qword ptr [rdx+8],rcx
00007ffa`02c41d61 488bc2          mov     rax,rdx
00007ffa`02c41d64 c3              ret
```

As I understand this, there is no struct allocated on the stack.